Lebesgue outer measure of image of function with bounded derivative on a bounded closed interval
The current question comes from This Earlier Question. I state this question again here:
Question: Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $[a, b]$ and $E\subseteq (a,b)$. Assume $f'$ exists and $|f'|\leq M$. Prove that
$$\lambda^*(f(E)) \leq M\lambda^*(E)$$
where $\lambda^*$ denotes the Lebesgue outer measure.
In the original post, the accepted answer from the user csh gives a proof based on Vitali's Covering lemma. However, I was wondering whether we could prove it without using any covering lemma.
Here is my proof:
Fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$. Given that $f'$ exists on $E$ and $|f'| \leq M$, we know that for any $x \in E$, there exists $\delta_{x,\varepsilon} > 0$ such that for any $y$ with $|y - x| \leq \delta_{x,\varepsilon}$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq (M + \varepsilon)|x - y|$.
Define, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{align*}
E_n = \{x \in E; |f(y) - f(x)| \leq (M + \varepsilon)|x - y| \text{ for any } y \in [a, b] \text{ with } |y - x| < \frac{1}{n}\}
\end{align*}
Note: (1) $\{E_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of subsets of $E$ with $E = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$; (2)$\{f(E_n)\}$ is also an increasing sequence of subsets with $f(E) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f(E_n)$
Next, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, from the basic properties of the Lebesgue outer measure, there exists a sequence $\{I_i\}$ of open intervals with $\lambda(I_i) < \frac{1}{n}, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$, such that
\begin{align*}
E_n \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda^*(E_n) + \varepsilon > \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda(I_i) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Since $\lambda(I_i) < \frac{1}{n}$ and by the construction of $E_n$, we have that $\forall x, y \in E_n \cap I_i$,
\begin{align*}
|f(y) - f(x)| \leq (M + \varepsilon)|x - y| \leq (M + \varepsilon)\lambda(I_i)
\end{align*}
This means that $f(E_n \cap I_i)$ is a subset of an interval with length at most $(M + \varepsilon)\lambda(I_i)$, which gives,
\begin{align*}
\lambda^*(f(E_n \cap I_i)) \leq (M + \varepsilon)\lambda(I_i) \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Note that $E_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (E_n \cap I_i)$ and $f(E_n) = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f(E_n \cap I_i)$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
    \lambda^*(f(E_n)) &\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda^*(f(E_n \cap I_i)) \\
    &\leq (M + \varepsilon)\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda(I_i) \quad \text{by (2)} \\
    &< (M + \varepsilon)(\lambda^*(E_n) + \varepsilon) \quad \text{by (1)} \\
    &\leq (M + \varepsilon)(\lambda^*(E) + \varepsilon) \quad \text{since } E_n \subseteq E \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Using the fact that the Lebesgue outer measure is regular and the continuity from below, we have
\begin{align*}
\lambda^*(f(E)) = \lambda^*\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f(E_n)\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda^*(f(E_n))
\end{align*}
By letting $n \to \infty$ on the left-hand side of (3), we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lambda^*(f(E)) \leq (M + \varepsilon)(\lambda^*(E) + \varepsilon)
\end{align*}
Finally, letting $\varepsilon \to 0$, we conclude
\begin{align*}
\lambda^*(f(E)) \leq M\lambda^*(E)
\end{align*}
Is my proof correct? I cannot identify any errors but am unsure about its correctness.

Your proof looks correct to me! You have carefully leveraged the boundedness of $f'$ to control $|f(y) - f(x)|$, and your use of the regularity and subadditivity of the Lebesgue outer measure is both standard and valid. The construction of $E_n$ as an increasing sequence and the approximation argument involving $\varepsilon$ are well-executed. By letting $\varepsilon \to 0$, you correctly deduced the desired inequality $\lambda^(f(E)) \leq M\lambda^(E)$ without relying on Vitali's Covering Lemma. Well done!
